# 2020 Developer Survey Error

Tags: support, bug, status-completed

I just finished the Developer Survey and after submitting i was redirected to and error page with the following content:

> Oops! Something Bad Happened! We apologize for any inconvenience, but
>   an unexpected error occurred while you were browsing our site.
>
> It’s not you, it’s us. This is our fault.
>
> Detailed information about this error has automatically been recorded
>   and we have been notified.
>
> Yes, we do look at every error. We even try to fix some of them.
>
> It’s not strictly necessary, but if you’d like to give us additional
>   information about this error, do so at our feedback site,
>   https://meta.stackoverflow.com.

Do i need to retake the survey?

Comment: Yep, happened to me too.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You don't need to retake the survey. Your responses have been recorded.

The issue here was with the code that dismisses the announcement banner. I turned that off while I figure out what exactly went wrong there, so nobody should be seeing this error page at the end of the survey anymore.

Thanks for the report!

Comment: @DavyM Thanks for confirming. I have the actual fix ready to deploy as well, and I guess I'll just have to take the survey myself after to be sure. :)